# How to scrape website table with expand button using Python?

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a database from this website - https://bezerocarbon.com/listings
*You can add in random personal details to unlock and see the full table.

I have used BeautifulSoup to extract and it works but it will not scrape the project details that is under the expand (+) button.

This is my Python code, I am not able to scrap details of the project in the expanded row:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://bezerocarbon.com/listings/'
result = requests.get(url)
content = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
print(result) #received Response 200

table = soup.find('table', role='table')

#extract column names
headers = table.find_all('th')
titles = []
for i in headers:
    title = i.text
    titles.append(title)

#creating pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=titles)

#extracting row details
#obtain all tr tags beccause of data are in rows, then obtain the details
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for i in rows[1:]: #this skips the first row which is the header
    tdata = i.find_all('td')
    #row = [tr.text for tr in data]
    row = [tr.text for tr in tdata]
    l = len(df)
    df.loc[l]=row

print(df)
```

[Final result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmxdd.png)
[Example of the missing result. I need to click the + button to see the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGsT4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is stored inside `<script>` tag in Json form. To parse it you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bezerocarbon.com/listings'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = soup.select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['props']['pageProps']['listingsData'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                     uuid         registryId        projectId status rating isOnWatch                      accreditor             sectorGroup                     sector                                   subSector                         locations                                                                                                                                                      name                                                                                                                                               displayName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          summaryAnalysis              vintage
0    00e2602d-c3a2-4b98-91ff-9c458a5bae1b              verra             1380  FINAL      B                                       VCS                  Energy                     Energy                                  Renewables                            Turkey                                                                                                                          Akinci Hydroelectric Power Plant                                                                                                                          Akinci Hydroelectric Power Plant                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      BeZero Carbon has reaffirmed the ‘B’ BeZero Carbon Rating assigned to credits issued by Turkey-based VCS 1380. This is based on our opinions and reasons expressed below following our analysis of publicly available information. Carbon credits rated ‘B’ provide a low likelihood of achieving 1 tonne of CO₂e avoidance or removal.\n\nThe reaffirmed ‘B’ rating continues to reflect our view that evidence concerning the favourable conditions for investing in hydropower in Turkey, relatively low costs and high penetration all indicate low additionality. However, the rating is bolstered by small relative risks of over-crediting despite a 10.8% variation in the grid emission factor over the crediting period, due to the application of continuous monitoring of electricity output. In addition, the project faces relatively low risks of leakage and non-permanence in our view, since the applied methodology is largely effective at mitigating potential risk. Lastly, we find that the project faces significant risks from a policy perspective due to the existence of far-reaching and effective government support.  24/10/18 - 30/09/21
1    01a4f557-62cd-40d7-8685-06b313b9f7b9              verra             1731  FINAL    BBB                                       VCS                  Energy                     Energy                           Energy Efficiency                             India                                                                                                                    CFL Lighting Scheme Bachat Lamp Yojana                                                                                                                    CFL Lighting Scheme Bachat Lamp Yojana                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             BeZero Carbon has removed from ‘rating watch’ and upgraded to ‘BBB’ (from ‘BB’) the BeZero Carbon Rating assigned to credits issued by the India-based VCS 1731. This is based on the opinions and reasons expressed below following our analysis of publicly available information. Carbon credits rated ‘BBB’ provide a moderate likelihood of avoiding or removing 1 tonne of CO₂e for every carbon credit issued.\n\nThe rating was placed on watch following BeZero’s continuous monitoring process. This review explored all risk factors, and included the role of carbon finance in the context of the project’s success, and the project’s registration across multiple registries. We have now concluded the review and are of the opinion that risks to carbon efficacy of VCS 1731 are somewhat lower than previously assessed.\n\nThe revised ‘BBB’ rating reflects our view that credits issued by this project face limited risk to additionality, considering the important role of carbon finance in the project’s success. However, we find there to be significant risk from a policy perspective, considering the project’s oversight by the Bureau for Energy Efficiency. We find some risk of over-crediting, with appropriate emission factors and robust monitoring, but a lack of usage data to verify assumptions. We also find limited risk of leakage, owing to deliberate leakage mitigation activity, although energy-efficient lighting may incentivise light usage; and limited non-permanence risk, given that in our view there is no risk of technical reversal but some concern over disclosure pertaining to issuance.   30/05/10 - 31/12/12
2    01b994ab-86d8-4fe3-b2ab-c89082b382f1              verra              929  FINAL      C        rw                             VCS                  Energy                     Energy                           Energy Efficiency                            Canada                                                            Energy Efficiency and Solid Waste Diversion Activities within the Quebec Sustainable Community                                                            Energy Efficiency and Solid Waste Diversion Activities within the Quebec Sustainable Community                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            BeZero Carbon has placed on ‘rating watch’ the ‘C’ BeZero Carbon Rating assigned to credits issued by the Canada-based VCS 929. This is based on the opinions and reasons expressed below following our analysis of publicly available information. A 'rating watch' could result in an upgrade, a downgrade or a reaffirmed rating.\n\nThe decision to place VCS 929 on 'rating watch' relates to new information related to additionality tests and example issuance calculations that cover various project activities and instances. These were not available at the time of the project's rating and therefore are not currently considered within our analysis. BeZero is reviewing these new documents and their implications across all risk factors.\n\nThe ‘C’ rating reflected the project’s low additionality given Canada’s robust energy efficiency standards and comparatively strong financial support for project activities, and significant over-crediting risks due to the scope for shifting baselines. It was further constrained by the project operating in a highly supportive policy environment, and by the presence of notable information risk, which counterbalanced the low technical risk of reversals. The rating was bolstered by minimal leakage concerns.  01/01/10 - 31/12/18
3    01eb1243-7ad1-4c62-bb1a-bee5ad323089              verra              426  FINAL      B                                       VCS                   Waste  Waste Handling & Disposal               Agricultural Methane Recovery                          Thailand                                                                                Wastewater Treatment with Biogas System in Palm Oil Mill at Sawi, Chumporn                                                                                Wastewater Treatment with Biogas System in Palm Oil Mill at Sawi, Chumporn                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         BeZero Carbon has reaffirmed the ‘B’ BeZero Carbon Rating assigned to credits issued by the Thailand-based VCS 426. This is based on our opinions and reasons expressed below, following our analysis of publicly available information. Carbon credits rated ‘B’ provide a low likelihood of achieving 1 tonne of CO₂e avoidance or removal. \n\nThe ‘B’ rating continues to reflect our view of the project’s limited additionality as its viability is likely not dependent on carbon finance. We find significant policy risk from the supportive policy environment, and some leakage risk also affects the project’s overall carbon efficacy, in our view, due to the environmental implications of palm oil production. The rating is bolstered, however, by strong measures to limit over-crediting through robust monitoring processes, while limited risk of non-permanence stems from some information uncertainties.  01/01/09 - 31/05/16

...
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thanks for your help, when I try to incorporate this code with minor adjustments, it produces an empty dataframe. Maybe I am not understanding this correctly. Will you be kind enough to finish the code for me? Thanks